# ANTLR How to use lexer rules having same starting?

Tags: antlr, grammar, lexer

How to use lexer rules having same starting?

I am trying to use two similar lexer rules (having the same starting):

```
TIMECONSTANT: ('0'..'9')+ ':' ('0'..'9')+;
INTEGER     : ('0'..'9')+;
COLON       : ':';
```

Here is my sample grammar:

```
grammar TestTime;

text      : (timeexpr | caseblock)*;

timeexpr  : TIME;
caseblock : INT COLON ID;

TIME      : ('0'..'9')+ ':' ('0'..'9')+;
INT       : ('0'..'9')+;
COLON     : ':';
ID        : ('a'..'z')+;

WS        : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

When i try to parse text:

```
12:44
123 : abc
123: abc
```

First two lines are parsed correctly, 3rd - generates error.
For some reason, '123:' ANTLR parses as TIME (while it is not)...

So, is it possible to make grammar with such lexems?

Having such rules is necessary in my language for using both case-blocks and datetime constants. For example in my language it is possible to write:

```
case MyInt of
  1: a := 01.01.2012;
  2: b := 12:44;
  3: ....
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon `DIGIT+ ':'` is matched, the lexer expects this to be followed by another `DIGIT` to match a `TIMECONSTANT`. If this does not happen, it cannot fall back on another lexer rule that matches `DIGIT+ ':'` and the lexer will not give up on the already matched `':'` to match an `INTEGER`.

A possible solution would be to optionally match `':' DIGIT+` at the end of the `INTEGER` rule and change the type of the token if this gets matched:

```
grammar T;  

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-15s '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
 ;

INTEGER      : DIGIT+ ((':' DIGIT)=> ':' DIGIT+ {$type=TIMECONSTANT;})?;
COLON        : ':';
SPACE        : ' ' {skip();};

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment TIMECONSTANT : ;
```

When parsing the input:

```
11: 12:13 : 14
```

the following will be printed:

```
INTEGER         '11'
COLON           ':'
TIMECONSTANT    '12:13'
COLON           ':'
INTEGER         '14'
```

### EDIT

> Not too nice, but works...

True. However, this is not an ANTLR short coming: most lexer generators I know will have a problem properly tokenizing such a `TIMECONSTANT` (when `INTEGER` and `COLON` are also present). ANTLR at least facilitates a way to handle it in the lexer :)

You *could* also let this be handled by the parser instead of the lexer:

```
time_const : INTEGER COLON INTEGER;
INTEGER    : '0'..'9'+;
COLON      : ':';
SPACE      : ' ' {skip();};
```

However, if your language's lexer ignores white spaces, then input like:

```
12 :    34
```

would also be match by the `time_const` rule, of course.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR lexers can't backtrack, which means once it reaches the ':' in the TIMECONSTANT rule it must complete the rule or an exception will be thrown. You can get your grammar working by using a predicate to test for the presence of a number following the colon.

```
TIMECONSTANT: ('0'..'9')+ (':' '0'..'9')=> ':' ('0'..'9')+;
INTEGER     : ('0'..'9')+;
COLON       : ':';
```

This will force ANTLR to look beyond the colon before it decides that it is in a TIMECONSTANT rule.

Comment: Close, but no cigar! :) This will produce an error when parsing `1:` which would not be tokenized as an `INTEGER` followed by a `COLON` (try it).